# Apps in the Windows registry not showing use the suggested code

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am using the approved answer from this post [Check if application is installed in registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379143/check-if-application-is-installed-in-registry) using Visual Studio but it is returning false. I checked the registry and the application is present there (path = Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{0CF1BFF6-5D97-4080-A6F5-B785C027095F}_is1). The code is working for user applications but its failing o local machine applications. Can someone help what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: 32bit vs 64bit registry namespaces?

Comment: I didn't get it what you are saying ? I am very new to this. The app is present in the give path and I am using the same path. Its not in the WOW6432Node.

Comment: Is your process, the one looking for the registry key, 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Nice! I tried it on x64 and it worked. Thanks